# VueJS 3 Reactive Form Submitted with Old Input Values

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, reactive-programming, vuejs3

In my vue.js 3 application I have the following scenario:
I have a toolbar component and a content component (`CustomContent`). The CustomContent contains a custom form component (`CustomForm`).
After a submit button in the toolbar was clicked, an event will be emitted from the toolbar to the CustomContent component
using mitt event bus.
On this event the CustomContent change the `content` parameter of the prop `formData` which is passed to the
CustomForm. Furthermore, the boolean prop `submit` will be set to true, which is also passed to the CustomForm. This submit
prop will be watched inside the CustomForm. If it is true, the form will be submitted.

In a nutshell:

```
   App
   ├─ Toolbar: emits event 'toolbarAction' to CustomContent via mitt emitter (eventBus)
   └─ CustomContent: on:toolbarAction -> set new content in formData and notify form to submit
      └─ CustomForm (formData & submit props given)
         └─ <form ref="form" />  -> this.$refs.submit() if submit==true
```

So far everything's look good. The new content is applied to the CustomForm. Everything's looks reactive at first.

But when the form inside CustomForm is submitted, a POST request containing the **old content** will be send to the server,
although the changes were applied. I can see it in the browser's console. I also can see, that the DOM of the form
was updated correctly:

```html
   <form action="/update/some/resource" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="some_token">
     <!-- input with new content -->
     <input type="hidden" name="content" value="new content">
   </form>
```

But for some reason the POST request contains the old initialized form state with 'old content'.

**CustomContent.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div>

    <custom-form
      :form-data="formData"
      :submit="submit"
    ></custom-form>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

import CustomForm from "./CustomForm";

export default {
  name: "custom-content",
  components: {
    CustomForm
  },

  props: {
    token: {
      type: String,
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      submit: false,
      newContent: 'new content',

      formData: {
        action: '/notebooks/36/notes/59',
        method: 'PUT',
        csrf_token: this.token,
        parameters: [
          { name: 'content', value: 'old content'} // content is initialized with some old content
        ]
      },

    }
  },
  mounted() {

    // register event toolbarAction (on toolbar button clicked)
    this.eventBus.on('toolbarAction', action => {

      if (this.formData) {

        // change input value of content to 'new content'
        this.formData.parameters[0].value = this.newContent;

        // submit prop in CustomForm will be watched. If submit==true, form will be submitted
        this.submit = true;
      }

    });
  }
}
</script>
```

**CustomForm.vue**

```js
<template>
  <div>

    <form
      :action="formData.action"
      method="post"
      ref="form"
    >
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" :value="formData.method" />
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="formData.csrf_token" />
      <input
        v-for="param in formData.parameters"
        type="hidden"
        :name="param.name"
        :value="param.value"
      />
    </form>

    <!-- input value of "content". Value is reactive and will change after event -->
    {{ formData.parameters[0].value }}

  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "custom-form",
  props: {
    formData: {
      type: Object,
      default: undefined
    },
    submit: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    content() {
      return this.formData.parameters.map(content => content.value)
    }
  },
  watch: {
    content(newValue) {
      console.log(newValue);
      console.log(this.$refs.form)
    },

    submit: function (value) {

      if (value === true) {

        // value of content = "new content"
        console.log(this.formData.parameters[0].value);
        // DOM of form was updated, correctly ->  <input type="hidden" name="content" value="new content">
        console.log(this.$refs.form);
        // but after submit() a request with "old content" will be sent to the server
        this.$refs.form.submit();
        
        // in Browser console: if I run window.myForm.submit() by myself, the new content will be submitted..
        // window.myForm = this.$refs.form;
      }
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here? Thanks.